# What is universal binary for iOS how iOS work at run time with them?

Tags: ios, xcode

A universal binary in ios contains executable for both armv7 and arm64. How iOS run architecture based executable.what is the concept of universal binary?
Xcode creates the universal by compiling for both architecture armv7 and arm64 then create the universal binary that contains executable for both in a single file. So my question is what happens when this universal file will run in deep, if anyone have any document related to it please share the link.
thanks in advance.

Comment: The executing environment / linker will take the part that is for the architecture the code is being run on and executes / links that part. It's quite simple by itself.

Comment: This quora thread will help you clear things, https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-universal-binary-codes-for-Xcode